# What is NerdAnswer and why do I find my question on this website too?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question on superuser and when I googled it I stumbled upon : [this website](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=475110) whith my question and username. I've never saw a link between superuser (and any SE site in general) and NerdAnswer so Is this a normal behaviour ?

Comment: Those are scraper sites – you can report them if they don't comply to the SE attribution rules.

Comment: It does, [as requested](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), link to your profile and to the original question. It does not, however, mention the CC BY-SA license. Not sure what the legality of that is.